# Run 2 queries at the same time on Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to retrieve quite a bit of data from our oracle DB and to do so I need to run 20+ queries. Is there any way to run more than one query at a time on the same connection?

I tried using / to separate the queries, but that simply opens multiple tabs and queries still run sequentially, although I don't have to start them one by one.

Comment: Why can't you open multiple connections/sessions?

Comment: when I try to run queries on different connections, it stops and runs the new one I specified... the first one doesn't finish :(

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using?  With 2.1.1 I can open two connections and run statements in each at the same time.  If the tab has a tilde followed by a number in it, the window is part of the same connection as another window.  For earlier versions of SQL Developer you could open multiple instances of the application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the simplest solution to this was to use SQL Plus that came with the rest of Oracle software. It's a clunky tool, but does what I needed, while I'm free to use SQL Developer for other queries.

Comment: If you have a very big result SQLPlus is not right tool.

Answer (score 63):

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will open a new unshared worksheet that can run queries in parallel. In that case you have to paste a query in each tab and run them manually though, but it is handy when just testing a few queries.

Comment: I think that's the most correct answer. Oracle SQL Developer will share connections by default [(documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31695/intro.htm#CHDHIFGJ). One hack is to have the same connection stored with different names. Un-shared worksheet allows queries to work using the same connection information but using a separate connection.

Answer (score 22):

In SqlDeveloper preferences: `Tools > Preferences > Database > Worksheet` check the option for `New Worksheet to use unshared connction`. This will allow you to execute multiple queries at the same time, each in each tab. See a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9otg.png) too.

Comment: Brilliant. Spending years in the SQL Server world, I find myself in Oracle-land asking, "Wait, I can't do what?" This is a HUGE help.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need a separate session per query.

Comment: Semantic quibble: technically, you will need a separate *session* per query. You can have multiple sessions per connection.

Answer (score 0):

@Tony is correct, each query must run in its own session to run in parallel. What tool are you using? In PL/SQL Developer, I can open a DB connection, then open multiple sessions within that connection and run several queries in "parallel" - I do have to execute each one manually, but if they each take a long time, perhaps that will get you what you need, or something similar in whatever tool it is you're using.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the free Oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you like to live dangerously, you can run multiple "threads" from one script using the pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION. For example:

```
DECLARE
   PROCEDURE foo(i IN PLS_INTEGER) AS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO qux
         SELECT * FROM bar
         WHERE baz = i;
      COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK;
   END;
BEGIN
   foo(1);
   foo(2);
   foo(3);
END;
```

Comment: The questions was about running `at the same time`. Your three procedure calls will execute sequentially.

Comment: No, they are invoked sequentially. Assuming they take more than a small fraction of a second to finish, they will execute in parallel.